APRSdroid -- Do I have the third method?
If I want ARPSdroid to send my positions continuously and automatically, I can use two methods: (1) keep screen on, or (2) an automation app, such as Tasker. My issue is: Do I have the third method? Thanks for reply.
I know methods 1 and 2 are good, but they kill battery of my smartphone quickly, so I need the third method.
